# excel matching two arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I have a problem that seems pretty easy, but still cannot find a proper solution, I want to avoid using vba.

I have two tables in one spreadsheet. both have the same columns - Name, City, Province. 
My goal is compare both and if three out of three values in a row match, then pull "1", if not, pull 0.

I have used the formulas below , but it does not work for my case .

`=IF(AND(A2=P:P,G2=M:M,H2=L:L),1,0)`

`=INDEX(A:P,MATCH(A2,P:P,FALSE),MATCH(G2,M:M,FALSE),2)`

`=INDEX(L:P,MATCH(A5,P:P,0),MATCH(G5,M:M,0),MATCH(H5,L:L,0))`

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(L2:L60=H2),--(M2:M60=G2),--(P2:P60=A2),B2:B60)`

It seems that the solution is quiet simple , but I cannot find it,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank for the reply! I compare rows with rows in these two tables. I will add the picture of a  result - if matches .  Can you please add this as an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption:  Values just need to exist, not that they need to be of equivalent row.

```
=If(IfError(Match(A2,P:P,0),0)*IfError(Match(G2,M:M,0),0)*IfError(Match(H2,L:L,0),0)>0,1,0)
```

---

For each IfError, you will output a row number (>0) if you match, or if there is no match a zero will be output.  Multiply anything by zero and you get zero, whcih allows a 1 or 0 output for true/false in the overarching If-statement.

---

If they need to be of the same row, you can compare 2 matches, which rely on the transitive property (A=B, B=C, so A=C):

```
=If(And(Match(A2,P:P,0)=Match(G2,M:M,0),Match(G2,M:M,0)=Match(H2,L:L,0)),1,0)
```

---

**Edit1:**

Per my comment (to this answer) about false negatives, a UDF or subroutine in VBA would be more appropriate, considering `Match()` returns the *first* row that has a match.

As this is not a VBA tagged post, this is a bit above the expected answer...  My recommendation would be to:

- A)  Ensure you are comfortable using VBA.
- B)  Make a post about creating a user-defined function (note that any post on here about VBA has an expectation that the poster can interact with an *expert* on the topic and will be putting forth effort to write the code themselves, as StackOverflow is not a code-for-you service).

To help give a lead on what *may* be in your UDF:

- A loop to go through the values from first row to last row in the search column (i.e., L, M, & P)
- A variable to dynamically identify the last row of your search column
- An if-statement to compare values from your lookup values (i.e., A2, G2, H2) to the search values at the current iteration of the loop
- An output of 1 (has match) or 0 (no match).

There are many ways to go about this with VBA; hopefully that's a good start for you, Irina!

Comment: @Irina Note that this can give false negatives!  If A2/G2/H2 have multiple matches, they can fail due to `Match()` returning the FIRST instance of a match.  If you want a more fool-proof plan, VBA would be appropriate so you can loop and output a value.  This could be done as a UDF (user-defined function) or a subroutine to output the desired value.

Comment: Cyril, you are right, it return even 0 - if 2 out of three values  matches.  can you please advise how I can you this UDF?

Comment: @Irina I just posted my recommendation for the UDF in my answer.  This will take your comfort in using VBA as well as making another post specific to your UDF.  Sorry that a simple excel formula doesn't appear to fit your desire ='/

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to merge the columns together, them `Match` on that.

Like this

```
=IFERROR( IF( MATCH(H3&"_"&I3&"_"&J3, $C$2:$C$60&"_"&$B$2:$B$60&"_"&$A$2:$A$60,0), "Yes"), "No")
```

Choose a seperator character that doesn't otherwise appear in your data (I've chosne `_`)